# groupby, shift, and average a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with three columns:

For each row, I want to take the average of the past n data points with the same column value (i.e., average over all dates less than the current date).

At below, I provided an example. "col" column is 'A' from row 5 to 55 and it is 1 for "value" column.

```
        dates col  value
0  2020-01-01   B      1
1  2020-01-02   B      10
2  2020-01-03   B      1
3  2020-01-04   A      1
4  2020-01-05   A      1
..        ...  ..    ...
56 2020-02-26   B      1
57 2020-02-27   B      1
58 2020-02-28   B      1
59 2020-02-29   A      1
60 2020-03-01   A      1
```

---

Desired output (with n =10)

```
         dates col  value
 0  2020-01-01   B      nan
 1  2020-01-02   B      1
 2  2020-01-03   B      11/2
 3  2020-01-04   A      1
 4  2020-01-05   A      1
 ..        ...  ..    ...
 56 2020-02-26   B      12/3
 57 2020-02-27   B      13/4
 58 2020-02-28   B      14/5
 59 2020-02-29   A      1
 60 2020-03-01   A      1
```

---

Desired output (with n=2)

```
         dates col  value
 0  2020-01-01   B      nan
 1  2020-01-02   B      1
 2  2020-01-03   B      11/2
 3  2020-01-04   A      1
 4  2020-01-05   A      1
 ..        ...  ..    ...
 56 2020-02-26   B      11/2
 57 2020-02-27   B      2/2
 58 2020-02-28   B      2/2
 59 2020-02-29   A      1
 60 2020-03-01   A      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked: `groupby` + `rolling.mean`; then `groupby` "col" again to `shift` (OP worked it out themself):

```
g = df.groupby('col')['value']
df['new_val'] = g.rolling(n, min_periods=1).mean().groupby(level = 0).shift()
```

Output:

```
        dates col  value  new_val
0  2020-01-01   B      1     1.00
1  2020-01-02   B     10     1.00
2  2020-01-03   B      1     5.50
3  2020-01-04   A      1     1.00
4  2020-01-05   A      1     1.00
56 2020-02-26   B      1     4.00
57 2020-02-27   B      1     3.25
58 2020-02-28   B      1     2.80
59 2020-02-29   A      1     1.00
60 2020-03-01   A      1     1.00
```

Comment: I believe I was looking for this: g.rolling(window=n, min_periods=1).mean().groupby(level = 0).shift() ... I still accept your solution since you showed me how to achieve it